# Tensorflow slows down/hangs randomly during training

Tags: tensorflow

[image: Notice the 22.436 secs in the middle there]
(Notice the 22.5 sec max in the middle)

In this case it took 22.5 seconds, in other cases it takes 200 seconds or hangs (it might unlock at some point in the future).

The fact that it usually unfreezes makes me think it isn't a deadlock. But I have no clue what it is. However, strace shows that the freeze occurs during a futex call, which is suspicious.

I'm not doing anything particularly complex; I have a FCN, and I only measure time running session.run(). Running on GPU, but I've tried running on CPU and it still happens.

Here's the time measurement code for reference:

```
            feed_dict = {
                self.prediction_network.data_placeholder: batch_data,
                self.prediction_network.groundtruth_placeholder: batch_results,
                self.prediction_network.learningrate_placeholder: learning_rate,
                self.prediction_network.dropout_placeholder: FLAGS.dropout_keep_prob
            }

            _, global_step, loss_value = session.run([self.prediction_network.train_op, self.prediction_network.global_step_op, self.prediction_network.loss],
                                    feed_dict=feed_dict)

            durations.append(time.time() - start_time)

            if global_step % 200 == 0:
                avgtime = sum(durations)/float(len(durations))
                maxtime = max(durations)
                mintime = min(durations)
                print('Step %d (E%d / %d): loss = %.5f (%.3f sec avg, %.3f sec max, %.3f sec min)' % (global_step, epoch+1, FLAGS.epoch_count, loss_value, avgtime, maxtime, mintime))
```

I've been stuck with this for a while and I can't get forward because whenever I try something I have to rerun it 10 times until it works. Anybody had this problem?

Comment: Can you look at your queue fullness statistics? They show up in tensorboard. Typical way to get slowdowns like this is when you get queue starvation. One solution is to add periodic `time.sleep` in your main thread to give Python a chance to schedule some data enqueing threads, some analysis here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840323/benchmark-of-howto-reading-data/39842628#39842628