# TensorFlow: Is dequeueing single examples a bottleneck?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

In the TF-slim [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/parallel_reader.py#L105) (with reference to the `read` function), I realized there are multiple readers that feed (enqueue) the parsed TF-examples into a queue, but there is a function `dequeue` that only dequeues one element at a time. Would this cause a bottleneck in my training when I create my batches? Is it better to use `dequeue_many` instead?

While I was training my model previously, I noticed on TensorBoard that the parallelreader queue is always full - is this a cause of concern or is the enqueue op supposed to be faster than the dequeue op? Generally speaking, should the dequeue operation dequeue as many examples as the number of readers that enqueue the operations?

Here are my visualizations for the queues:
[image: Queue Visualization]

My guess is that it is probably good to have more examples dequeued at any one time, so long as there is a min_after_dequeue argument that ensures enough examples in the queue to be shuffled at any one point (in fact, how often does the shuffling take place?). But what is the trade off of dequeuing many examples at one go?

Comment: If queue is full it could mean any part of downstream pipeline is a bottleneck, ie convolution layer, etc. I would suspect those before blaming dequeue

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do have a rather slow GPU (800 series) so i limited my batch size to something rather small. May I know if a single dequeue op typically happens fast enough after multiple readers enqueue? What is a tradeoff of using this versus dequeue_many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647784/tfrecordreader-seems-extremely-slow-and-multi-threads-reading-not-working/41688401#41688401) shows how to do profiling, and for that example, each dequeue op took 60 microseconds on one thread. If you use `tf.batch` on top of dequeue, it'll run multiple dequeue ops in parallel, so it may go down to 12 microseconds per deqeueue on average. This mean that it will only be a bottleneck if your computation takes less than 12 microseconds. A while back when I checked, it took 5 microseconds to schedule a single GPU kernel call, so any network with more than 2 GPU ops will take longer to evaluate, and `dequeue` will not be a bottleneck.

Comment: By a GPU Op, do you mean a single `sess.run` call? If I run multiple operations in a run like `sess.run([train_op, metrics_op])` would this constitute two GPU op, and would the size of the graph built affect the GPU call time? One thing I have found in the documentation is that there is a dequeue op done before the dequeue operations by `train.batch`. Would this single dequeue operation be fast enough to not cause a bottleneck in the enqueue operation of `train.batch`?

Comment: The way I imagine how the tensors flow is: enqueue tf-examples in parallel in RandomShuffleQueue (parallel readers) --> dequeue tf-examples singularly  (parallel readers)
--> decode one tf-example to a set of image and label tensors (decoder) --> enqueue tensors in `tf.train.batch` in parallel into a FIFO queue internally but one-by-one (train.batch)
--> use dequeue_many to dequeue one batch of examples (train.batch) --> for preprocessing/inference etc.