# Scale-out performance limitations for scatter-gather pattern in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Scale-out performance for scatter-gather dataflow pipelines is limited, and I am not sure if this is

- a bug in Tensorflow ([I was told that it wasn't](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7415#event-957548310))
- an underperformant way to design a graph for a distributed session

I use Tensorflow to build custom pipelines (i.e. I write my own OpKernels) of "embarrassingly parallel" problems (no coordination between "local" pipelines required). Typically these involve the local pipeline being replicated across all the machines in my cluster, and having a source and sink queue to feed input and receive output, respectively.

There is *no* coordination between the pipelines on individual machines, except for

- dequeuing input from the "source" queue
- enqueuing output to the "sink" queue

As the exact codebase I use is still closed source, I created a [similar example in vanilla Tensorflow](https://gist.github.com/samwhitlock/3b099f8489909a3293b3e4239a7188d0). I installed via pip (v0.12.1).

This script replicates my "local" pipeline by a while loop that induces a certain delay. The efficiency of this while loop is besides the point. The point is that the speedup I see when I scale this out across machines is not very good. [Here is the data I collected on a cluster of 10 machines](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ht8O9OT4csfYVOxSDybojXnZ-_uV2A60CF9Jt0jhps0/edit#gid=492424317) (only goes up to 9 because the machine hosting the source/sink queues is "unloaded").

[image: scale-out performance of nodes]

The ideal time is flat because the workload scales up linearly with the number of nodes (and should therefore take a constant time regardless of the number of nodes).

My question is

- Is this a known limitation of Tensorflow? I currently sidestep this by using ZeroMQ to coordinate between local nodes (i.e. I *don't* use the distributed session), and I know others who use MPI or other such non-TF systems.
- Is there a way to make this scatter-gather pattern faster by some primitive in Tensorflow that I'm currently not using, or perhaps by a way to construct graphs to require less coordination when executing?

Comment: Are you facing queue starvation? Your current implementation leaves parallelization of enqueue and dequeue parts to Python, and Python handling of concurrency is not great (here's one [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39842628/419116) where Python thread scheduling leads to queue starvation). An alternative is to have each worker run in it's own process. That's the most common pattern for distributed ML in TensorFlow, here's a toy non-Machine Learning example -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/ea1b1bae0a75c4aae593df7eca72d9ca

Comment: This is a good approach, but the only pitfall for my application (vs. the nice example you provided, or the while_loop simulation I posted) is that the unit of work for my custom application can vary significantly. Instead of some fixed amount of latency to process one queue element, it can take a lot longer. Sharding apriori (and separating into processes like this) would leave a lot of stragglers due to work imbalance. i.e. I would very much prefer to have minimal or no sharding of the workload.

Comment: There's no sharding in my example -- each worker has infinite work-load, runs independently and updates global state after each step independent of other workers. In your example, workers are triggered by sess.run(host_final_values) which contains results from all workers. This means that system will wait until all workers complete before finishing and starting another run call, so the fastest workers will be idle

Comment: There's no sharding in my example -- each worker has work-load controlled by FLAGS.iters (could be set to be different for each worker), runs independently and updates global state after each step independent of other workers. In your example, workers are triggered by sess.run(host_final_values) which contains results from all workers. This means that system will wait until all workers complete before finishing and starting another run call, so the fastest workers will be idle

Comment: Ah I see. So the separation of the param servers from the workers allows the workers to _push_ their completed values instead of my sample code, where the queue runners on the local process constantly _pull_ on the host_final_values. Is this the primary difference?

Also, is this a common pattern when using the distributed session? I understand why it performs better than my naive example, but it seems like a common enough pattern that something may already exist in Tensorflow.

Comment: Yes, the primary difference is that I use N clients/processes launching N independent enqueue calls, and you use 1 client/process with a single (large) enqueue call. This is a common pattern and most distributed training use it like distributed [inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception), implemented in Supervisor (getting replaced with MonitoredTrainingSession). There's quite a bit of training-specific stuff in MonitoredTrainingSession though, easier to start from scratch IMHO.