# Execution time slow down at beginning and raising later

Tags: performance, tensorflow

This is execution time log
As you can see, it faster and faster until it used 1.5 sec for one iteraction
and then slower and slower

```
iter: 0/700000
loss:8.13768323263
speed: 4.878s / iter

iter: 1/700000
loss:4.69941059748
speed: 3.162s / iter
...
...
...
iter: 1560/700000
loss:2.16679636637
speed: 1.496s / iter

iter: 1561/700000
loss:2.9271744887
speed: 1.496s / iter
...
...
...
iter: 3698/700000
loss:1.47574504217
speed: 1.701s / iter

iter: 3699/700000
loss:1.75555475553
speed: 1.701s / iter
```

Using `graph.finalize()` to freeze graph
install tensorflow 1.0 from source, using `jemalloc`, build with `XLA`, `SSE`...etc

```
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)
sess.graph.finalize()  # Graph is read-only after this statement.
```

and follow this [github](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet/blob/master/train_msc.py#L233) to implement image_reader and accumulate gradients (like `iter_size` in caffe), all OP are outside training loop

not sure if relevant
GPU memory grow slightly, from 5707 MiB to 5717MiB
GPU-util become low and strange
1% -> 59% -> 1% -> 99% -> 0% -> 54% -> 1% -> 48%

anyone met this situation before?
or have any suggestion to debug?

Comment: My first suspicion is that you have bottleneck in your data input pipeline. You can monitor queue.size for all your queues to make sure they never become close to empty

Comment: I'm using `tf.train.slice_input_producer` and `tf.train.batch` in my pipeline. Doesn't use `FIFOQueue`, It seems there is no `queue.size`? And I tried to test run pipeline only for 100k, it used 0.004 sec/iter, does this test is referenceable? [Gist, start from class ImageReader](https://gist.github.com/xxi511/0c1e6c265a15b297f024ff6c7a0567b0)

Comment: One way to debug is to look at timeline. The issue with `tf.train.batch` is that it uses a Queue which is CPU-only. So if your data is on GPU, it will go to CPU, and then back on GPU. Relevant issues for debugging: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840323/benchmark-of-howto-reading-data  2. motivations of slice_input_producer (the only producer that doesn't create queue) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7314 3. GPU resident queue in progress https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722

Comment: Interesting thing is it never reach 1.5 sec/iter again after re-run, try to find other way to improve, thanks