# What are the performance problems with "in-graph replication" in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I've heard there are performance problems with "in-graph replication". What are they? Why do they exist?

Answer (score 0):

Within-graph replication uses a single client process to drive execution, so this can become a bottleneck during replicated training.

Suppose you do model parallelism with 50 independent workers using single client.

1. This client would need to construct computation graph for all replicas. So if you have 50 replicas, this client has to handle 50x larger graph.
2. This client would need to drive session run calls for all replicas. If you are using Python client, you could have 50 threads in your client issuing session.run calls concurrently, but Python has performance issues with threads (GIL and thread scheduling issues like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39842628/419116))